# Unidentified Network - Ethernet - Windows 10 - Public Internet Connection

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I just moved back into my apartment at school for the new Semester.

My PC uses ethernet for the internet at home and here. It was working fine at home, but once I got to school it never worked. I get the error saying `Unidentified Network No internet access`. When I tried the troubleshooting it says `One or more network protocols are missing on this computer`.

I've tried all the simple stuff like restarting my computer and unplugging the cables. I've uninstalled and reinstalled my network adapter. When I run `ipconfig` on cmd line there is no IP address, as in blank, for Default Gateway. my DHCP says it is enabled and is set to find the IP automatically. This has been going on for a few days and I can't think of anything else to try.

The internet comes with my apartment and I have no access to the router. I was using this connection on this computer last semester without any issues at all.

If you need any more information let me know. I'm on my laptop right now using the WiFi fine, but I don't know if they have separate setups for wired and wireless internet.

Comment: See answer by rick98382 http://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/30073-network-protocols.html

Comment: Or this, read top 2 comments for fixes, video is waste of time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPpDM1OOQ4o

Comment: Neither of these seemed to help, I am hoping to avoid wiping my computer with a clean OS install as I don't have an easy way to back up

Comment: Does any other pc work on that ethernet connection?

Comment: You may need to speak to whoever is the admin for the router. Perhaps the router is still configured with the mac address of the previous person living in the apartment?

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem after uninstall Network Driver **(RealTec PCIe FE Family Controller)**

1: Uninstall RealTec PCIe FE Family Controller (PC->Manage->Network Driver)

2: Wifi Off, Airplan mode Off

3: Plug your Ethernet Wire

4: Will start identifying and **Done**.

Thanks